# How to display user input from textfield to a label?

Tags: java, swing

The problem I am trying to figure out is, how can I take user input from "Crew" textfield and have some text and the user input onto a label? For clarification I am using Apache Netbeans IDE.

[image]

I have tried with if statement, but I'm not sure how to do it right.

```
private void tf1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if(tf1.int > 2) {
        lb1.setText("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, error, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Comment: Be aware the actionPerformed() method is not called when you edit the field but when you press enter.

Comment: What is `tf1.int`? Maybe you want to get the text from tf1 and convert it to an integer? ie `Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read input from a JTextfield by running the [getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) method.
Set a label text by running the setText() method. All you need is a trigger.
That one could be a listener getting notified of changes on the JTextField. This is documented at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html.

An example can look like this:

```
    jtextfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel();
        }
        
        private void updateLabel() {
            jlabel.setText(jtextfield.getText());
        }
    });
```